# Prove equivalence of two conditions to be a smooth $k$-manifold $M^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

For the first couple classes of differential geometry, we have used the more concrete characterization of a manifold (given in #1 below). I am trying to prove that the following two conditions are equivalent for $M^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

1. For all $p\in M$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and $I = \{i_1, \dotsc, i_{k}\} \subseteq \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ such that $M \cap U$ is the graph of a smooth function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^I \overset{\text{open}}{\supseteq} V \to \mathbb{R}^{I^c} $
2. For all $p \in M$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a diffeomorphism $F: U \to F(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $M\cap U = F^{-1} (\mathbb{R}^k)$,

where we view $\mathbb{R}^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I'd like to use the "[submersion version](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~khonda/math535a/notes.pdf#page=13)" of the implicit function theorem, but that gives a projection to $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, not $\mathbb{R}^k$. I'm kind of stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: unless $\phi$ is injective in condition 1. I'm not so sure these are equivalent. Usually the patch definition of manifold comes with some assumption of injectivity...

Comment: OK, I'll have to think about whether that is included. For now you can assume it, though.